# Issue with nth-child(n), repetition not acting same as the first bulk

Tags: css

I'm creating a grid layout where the layout pattern repeats itself after 23 occurrences. The 24th and 25th block in the grid seem to appear correctly, but the following blocks do not show in the same way as they would in the first 23.

It seems that it works with certain view widths if I resize it.

The question is, why is it acting differently when it comes to the 26th block?

You can see the code example and how it's breaking up in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/woaozv7e/)

```css
   .content {
     width: 100%;
     margin-top: -5px;
     margin-right: -5px;
     position: relative;
     height: 100%;
   }
   
   .grid {
     width: 100%;
     font-size: 0;
   }
   
   .block {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 5px;
     width: calc(20% - 10px);
     padding-bottom: calc(20% - 10px);
     vertical-align: top;
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+14),
   .block:nth-child(23n+18),
   .block:nth-child(23n+19),
   .block:nth-child(23n+20),
   .block:nth-child(23n+5),
   .block:nth-child(23n+6),
   .block:nth-child(23n+7),
   .block:nth-child(23n+8),
   .block:nth-child(23n+9) {
     margin-top: calc(-20% + 5px)
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+1),
   .block:nth-child(23n+11),
   .block:nth-child(23n+20),
   .block:nth-child(23n+6) {
     width: calc(40% - 10px);
     padding-bottom: calc(40% - 10px)
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+20) {
     float: right;
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+5) {
     margin-left: calc(40% + 5px)
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+10) {
     margin-left: calc(-60% + 5px)
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+15) {
     margin-left: calc(-20% + 5px)
   }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d0c7dd"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #68d2e7"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #001fc9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #0c8eec"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d0c7dd"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #68d2e7"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #001fc9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #0c8eec"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #68d2e7"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #001fc9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #68d2e7"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #001fc9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #68d2e7"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #001fc9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem?  2nd cycle of 23 is not colored same as 1st cycle or last element is not properly placed?

Comment: The float:right on the 20th element is certainly one of the causes...

Comment: @amit77309 The color is just randomly set in the HTML, the issue is at certain view sizes the 26th block doesn't show on the same line as the 25th.   For example if I open the code snippet in fullscreen at my resolution the layout breaks.

Comment: @salketer Yes it will somewhat fix it by removing the float, but that breaks other parts of the layout. However thanks for making me move my attention towards this block, as i found out what was causing the issue. It was a added margin to the bottom forcing the next row to break.

Comment: I do not see 25&26 being appart at different screen size :I  added a counter to see easily which is which https://jsfiddle.net/woaozv7e/2/ I might also misunderstand the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 20th block (large) which was floated right had an added margin on the bottom which messed up the layout for the next row.
[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/woaozv7e/1/)

```css
   .content {
     width: 100%;
     margin-top: -5px;
     margin-right: -5px;
     position: relative;
     height: 100%;
   }
   
   .grid {
     width: 100%;
     font-size: 0;
   }
   
   .block {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 5px;
     width: calc(20% - 10px);
     padding-bottom: calc(20% - 10px);
     vertical-align: top;
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+14),
   .block:nth-child(23n+18),
   .block:nth-child(23n+19),
   .block:nth-child(23n+20),
   .block:nth-child(23n+5),
   .block:nth-child(23n+6),
   .block:nth-child(23n+7),
   .block:nth-child(23n+8),
   .block:nth-child(23n+9) {
     margin-top: calc(-20% + 5px)
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+1),
   .block:nth-child(23n+11),
   .block:nth-child(23n+20),
   .block:nth-child(23n+6) {
     width: calc(40% - 10px);
     padding-bottom: calc(40% - 10px)
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+20) {
     float: right;
     margin-bottom: 0;
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+5) {
     margin-left: calc(40% + 5px)
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+10) {
     margin-left: calc(-60% + 5px)
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+15) {
     margin-left: calc(-20% + 5px)
   }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d0c7dd"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #68d2e7"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #001fc9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #0c8eec"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d0c7dd"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #68d2e7"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #001fc9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #0c8eec"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #68d2e7"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #001fc9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #68d2e7"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #001fc9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #68d2e7"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #001fc9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

23+15 element in your current fiddle shows extra block at end. If this is your problem then

0+15 is also showing that same block there.

So nth-child(23n+x) is working properly. Thats how your logic is working.

Edit:

https://jsfiddle.net/amitatfusion/s18vxcbu/

Only Html file is changed (Now have 15 elements)

```css
   .content {
     width: 100%;
     margin-top: -5px;
     margin-right: -5px;
     position: relative;
     height: 100%;
   }
   
   .grid {
     width: 100%;
     font-size: 0;
   }
   
   .block {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 5px;
     width: calc(20% - 10px);
     padding-bottom: calc(20% - 10px);
     vertical-align: top;
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+14),
   .block:nth-child(23n+18),
   .block:nth-child(23n+19),
   .block:nth-child(23n+20),
   .block:nth-child(23n+5),
   .block:nth-child(23n+6),
   .block:nth-child(23n+7),
   .block:nth-child(23n+8),
   .block:nth-child(23n+9) {
     margin-top: calc(-20% + 5px)
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+1),
   .block:nth-child(23n+11),
   .block:nth-child(23n+20),
   .block:nth-child(23n+6) {
     width: calc(40% - 10px);
     padding-bottom: calc(40% - 10px)
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+20) {
     float: right;
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+5) {
     margin-left: calc(40% + 5px)
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+10) {
     margin-left: calc(-60% + 5px)
   }
   
   .block:nth-child(23n+15) {
     margin-left: calc(-20% + 5px)
   }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
 <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
 <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
 <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
 <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
 <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
 <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
 <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
 <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
 <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
 <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
 <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
 <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
 <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
 <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: @amit77309 I couldn't see the extra block you are referring to, however my issue didn't appear until the 26th block. Check my answer and see if you still see the issue at 15th block.